# Weird linux permission behavior

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, file-permissions

On a CentOS7 system I installed samba to create a share for windows clients using the following steps:

```
mkdir /samba/myShare
```

Then I definded `/samba/myShare` as my shared folder via the `smb.conf` file. After that, I did the following steps:

```
chmod 777 /samba/myShare #(drwxrwxrwx)
mkdir /samba/myShare/myFolder
chmod 774 /samba/myShare/myFolder #(drwxrwxr--)
```

Now I thought that the `myFolder` directory would be protected against changing its name or deleting it via Windows users by giving just read-permission to "other users" but that was not the case. The directory itself remained writeable. Then I was googling for it and came to the point that the directory remained writable because as a child-directory it takes the permissions from his mother-directory, which is `/samba/myShare` in my case. But now comes the strange thing that confuses me a lot:

- When I do a `chmod 773 /samba/myShare/myFolder` (`drwxrwx-wx`) I am not able to change or delete the directory itself via Windows anymore. Could someone please explain what this is all about?
- Why can I delete and change `myfolder` via the Windows client when I set the permissions to `drwxrwxr--` and cannot delete or change it when I set the permissions to `drwxrwx-wx`?

The entry in the `smb.conf` may be helpful:

```
[global]
workgroup = SAMBA
security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam
printing = cups
printcap name = cups
load printers = yes
cups options = raw
map to guest = bad user`
`[myShare]
comment = myShare
path = /samba/myShare
public = yes
writeable = yes
```

Oh yeah: I know that setting 777-permissions is not very common but this was just for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unix erasing or renaming a file/directory is an action on its parent directory. The access flags apply to the inode pointed to by the name.

Comment: Sounds clear to me but still the fact that setting permissions to (drwxrwxr--) lets me erase and renaming the folder but (drwxrwx-wx) does not, is confusing me. If it's true what you wrote then this change should take no effect on this because I didn't change anything in the parent directory. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If the directory isn't readable commands that should erase it cannot access the inodes of its files/subdirectries and therefore cannot empty it. So if the directory is not empty you cannot erase it on Linux, even with `rm -rf` (you can still rename it). If it's empty then it is erasable.

Comment: Really good remark that point with the empty folder, I didn't know that, thanks a lot!!!